# Adding caption to image_tag Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was wondering how to add a caption to my image_tag in rails. Here is what it loos like:

```
<%= image_tag "img1.jpg", :class => "rounded float-left", :height => '400px' %>
```

Is there anyway to add a caption beneath this picture that I have. 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no Rails helper for this that I'm aware of, but something like this should give you a caption below the image:

```
<figure>
    <%= image_tag "img1.jpg", :class => "rounded float-left", :height => '400px' %>
    <figcaption>Caption goes here</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a title with `:title => "title"` if you consider that a caption. If not, it's best to create a helper that outputs the image with a text centered and aligned immediately below.

Example:

```
<div class="figure">
  <img src=""/>
  <p class="caption">
    <span class="caption-text">Some caption of any length</span>
   </p>
</div>
```